# HTTPS Request with SOAP Web Service

Tags: java, android, asp.net-web-api, soap-client, webservice-client

Hello I'm wondering how could I make a https request for soap API.

In Android app, I had searched a lot but there isn't clear tutorial explaining how to do that.

Any suggestion or help please?

Thanks

Comment: Why u still want to use SOAP ? Use Rest service.

Comment: the apis which i use SOAP  i haven't the authorization to change it to rest

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.net.ssl.*;

public class HttpsClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String httpsURL = "https://postman-echo.com/post";
        URL myUrl = new URL(httpsURL);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) myUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        out.append("<xml><body>your SAOP request here</body></xml>");

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

        String inputLine;
        System.out.println("Response code is : "+conn.getResponseCode());
        System.out.print("Response text is :");
        while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        br.close();
    }

}
```

SOAP request is also an http POST with an xml in the request body. You need to change the url to the web service endpoint url and replace the sample string with your SOAP request.